# v-model fires change event twice

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vuex

I have an object in store and I use this as computed property in a component. There I have a form with input with v-model='obj.name'. and I have a method on change this input, that dispatch action for send this obj to API and call mutation for update state on successful response. The issue is that change event fires twice.

I update input, method on change fires, I got successful response and method on change fires again.

This is my input:

```
    <v-text-field dense
      v-model="object.name"
      @change="submitForm"                                              
 ></v-text-field>
```

```
computed:{
    ...mapGetters(['object']),
}
```

Method:

```
  methods:{
            submitForm(){
               {
                   return this.$store.dispatch('updateObject', this.object)
                        .then(() => {
                            alert('Data is saved')
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            alert(`Data is not saved. ${error}`)
                        })

            },
}
```

And this is my action:

```
 updateObject(context, object){
            return axios
                .put(`/api/object/${context.state.objectId}`,  object)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response)
                    context.commit('updateObject', order)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
```

I got successful alert, after I close it, change event is fired again

Answer (score 2):

I think its because v-model is bi-directional and @change fires whenever v-model value changes. Therefore @change fires once when the user updates the value and fires a second time because the value is updated by your vuex action.

Comment: How can I avoid this double update? That's mean I use not correct way for manage the state data.

Comment: You could simply include a button that calls submitMethod when clicked and remove the @change trigger.